# Cron and Ruby.. Does "puts `system command`" do anything?

Tags: ruby, linux, tar, cron

Quick question on cron with ruby,

I have a script which runs

```
puts `tar etc..`
```

I'm trying to debug why this script isn't tarring up the files like it should..

It works fine when I invoke it manually and i see the tar output too..

Does puts actually do anything when its run in a cron job?

Thanks

Daniel

Comment: I don't speak ruby, but doesn't `puts` just output the string? why should i ever _do_ something like call `tar`?

Comment: @hop Backticks are one of Ruby's ways of calling e.g. `system(...)`

Comment: This should work - more details please.

Answer (score 3):

From the crontab helping page:

> If standard output and standard error are not redirected by commands executed from the crontab entry, any generated output or errors shall be mailed, via an implementation-defined method, to the user.

What I usually do for debugging crontabs is creating a Logger:

```
logfile = File.open('/path/to/log.log', 'rw')
logger = Logger.new(logfile)
logger.debug('something')
```

Answer (score 1):

if you have the privilege to install gems, you can try minitar, instead of depending on system tar.

```
require 'zlib'
require 'archive/tar/minitar'
include Archive::Tar
File.open('test.tar', 'wb') do |tarfile|
    Archive::Tar::Minitar::Writer.open(tarfile) do |tar|
        Dir["file*"].each do |file|
            if File.file?(file) 
             tar.add_file(file, :mode =>0644, :mtime =>Time.now) { |stream, io|
                 stream.write( File.open(file).read )
             }
            end
        end
    end
end
```